# Crear Boton para regresar a la aplicacion Android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Tengo 2 Actividades: Mainactivity.xml y Mensajes_predet.xml

Tengo un boton que me dirige a la segunda actividad sin problema y esta misma va a mandar otras actividades, pero en cada una debo de colocar un boton (imagebutton) que me de regreso para la actividad anterior, para explicarme mejor:

Si estoy en la actividad Mensajes_predet, me regrese a la Main

tengo que crear un intent?

Este es mi imagebutton para regresar a Mainactivity

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
    android:src="@drawable/back"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true">
</ImageButton>
<!-- how to make this imaggebutton to return to Mainactivity??? -->
```

Y esto es lo que tengo en el manifiesto

```
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MensajesPredet"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_mensajes_predet" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

Y esto en mi archivo MainActivity.java

```
package com.globalstar.st300r;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    /** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
    public void predefinido(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MensajesPredet.class);
                startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Y si finalizas la actividad cuando quieras regresar? O tienes logica de negocio que te impide eso?

Comment: Bienvenido Pablo!, te sugiero leer [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y realiza el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos. (https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Pero como funciona?  a traves de finish() ? perdona la pregunta tonta pero soy novato y apenas estoy "jugando" con algunas funciones
@OmarMartinez

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si iniciaste `MensajesPredet` desde `MainActivity` de esta forma:

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(this, MensajesPredet.class);
  startActivity(intent);
```

para regresar a `MainActivity` solo usa el método `finish()` para cerrar MensajesPredet y regresar a `MainActivity`

> Tengo un boton que me dirige a la segunda actividad sin problema y
>   esta misma va a mandar otras actividades, pero en cada una debo de
>   colocar un boton (imagebutton) que me de regreso para la actividad
>   anterior

Si deseas regresar a la `Activity` anterior solo llama `finish();` desde tu botón.

---

En otro caso si la `Activity` fue destruida mediante `finish();`, por ejemplo:

```
   Intent intent = new Intent(this, MensajesPredet.class);
   startActivity(intent);
   finish();
```

necesitas realizar un Intent para volver a cargar la Activity que destruiste, en realidad no regresas ya que no existe, lo que estas realizando en este caso es cargarla de nuevo.

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
  startActivity(intent);
```

---

Como llamar el método finish(); desde un boton, para esto se usa un [OnclickListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html) , ejemplo:

```
ImageButton button= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton); //Obten la referencia mediante el id del boton.
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        finish(); //finaliza Activity.
    }
});
```